# ¿En que casos es necesario llamar al Garbage Collector (Recolector de basura) manualmente a través del método System.gc( ) en JAVA?

Tags: java, poo, rendimiento

No se si en programas complejos como IDEs: IntelliJ, eclipse, netbeans entre otros lo ocupen en algún momento para liberar de forma más eficiente recursos del sistema manualmente (hablando claro está de su código fuente de esos IDEs y no al momento de programar sobre ellos)

Por ejemplo al destruir un objeto dándole valor null, seguido de invocar el método System.gc( ) sería una buena práctica?

Comment: Hola.. Miraste el [tour] y tambien [ask]? Los votos en las preguntas y respuestan representan la calidad y claridad de las mismas. Esta pregunta parece ser basada en opiniones. Tal vez por eso recibiste un -1. Trata de que la pregunta sea lo mas clara posible y que no se base en opiniones.

Comment: No es la primera pregunta que hago, más bien creo que no es una pregunta clásica y común, pero no quiere decir que no esté bien formulada. Va dirigida a programadores con experiencia. Saludos

Comment: No es cuestion de formulación si no que StackOverFlow es para dudas puntuales sobre codigo directo, no sobre teoria.

Comment: Bueno a todo esto: Alguien es capaz de responder a mi duda? En el detalle de mi pregunta hago alusión a un fragmento de código que no es código como tal directamente pero hago la referencia.

Comment: @JDev Permíteme discrepar: nosotros no tenemos en español un [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) en español, con lo que las preguntas teóricas deberían tener cabida en SOes

Comment: Bueno, gracias por compartir sus conocimientos y aclarar mis dudas. Tengan bien dia.

Comment: Segun esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481185/73749 El gc es no deterministico, por lo tanto no lo estas llamando hagas lo que hagas...

Comment: @PabloLozano no si se basan en opiniones.

Comment: Mientras ya me quitaron mis 3 puntos solo por no hacer las preguntas que a ellos les gustan si al final de cuentas es un tema de performance en una aplicación escrita con CÓDIGO. Por eso la comunidad en español no crece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos casos en los que puedes necesitar *forzar*<sup>1</sup> la recolección de basura:

- **En un entorno de pruebas** donde estás buscando *memory leaks* (fugas de memoria). Justo antes de comprobar cuanta memoria está usando tu aplicación puede ser útil que la JVM haga una limpieza. En general, la propia JVM suele elegir el momento apropiado para llamar al GC, por lo que tu programa intente forzar la llamada suele ser innecesario.
- **En un sistema en *tiempo real duro***: Es un caso muy improbable puesto que Java no está pensado para trabajar en estos entornos, [pero se han creado implementaciones de JVM para sistemas de tiempo real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java). Cuando haces una llamada al GC, la JVM *congela* la ejecución de la aplicación, la examina, libera la memoria no usada y *descongela la ejecución*. Si el GC se ejecuta justo cuando tu aplicación debe recibir una llamada que no puede esperar (el GC puede congelar el sistema unos milisegundos), la aplicación puede fallar en su cometido. En estas JVM puedes pedir una pasada del GC para asegurarte de que en el momento justo tu sistema esté *activo*.

<sup>1</sup> Una llamada a System.gc() no asegura que el GC se ejecuta, es una *sugerencia* a la JVM, que puede ignorar (o no). Depende totalmente de la implementación de la misma.

Comment: Gracias, ya ven que fácil es compartir su conocimiento!. Al final de cuentas está relacionado con nuestro código. Y tenemos que tener bien claro estos temas también como desarrolladores profesionales. Saludos y gracias, me ayudaste mucho con tu respuesta .

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada para *cerrar la pregunta* (marcarla como respondida) si te ha sido útil